# Bootstrap radio button append markup when active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the javascipt radio button from Bootstrap 3

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Option 1 (preselected)
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.btn').button()
```

I need to append this only when ".btn" has class "active":

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

to obtain

```
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><!-- appended markup -->
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Option 1 (preselected)
  </label>
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just do it in plain 'ole CSS like this:

**CSS:**

```
.add-check .active:before {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    content: "\e013";
}
```

**HTML:** (I only added a class `.add-check` to the button group so you can target specific ones).

```
<div class="btn-group add-check" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Option 1 (preselected)
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
    </label>
</div>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/pjHAg/)

Comment: ah crap, I think I like your answer more than my own :( ... guess I should give you +1 :-p

Comment: LMAO...yeah, sometimes I feel like that too. Thanks for the +1.

Comment: Ain't no love for the jQuery people out there... Nice, pure CSS solution, this takes more skill.

Comment: this is a brilliant solution! Thanks @jme11

Answer (score 1):

You know, just to throw a pure CSS solution into the mix for the heck of it:

```
.active-display-only { display:none; }
.active > .active-display-only { display:inline-block; }
```

Then, put the glyphicon in each button:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok active-display-only"></span>
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Option 1 (preselected)
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in some jQuery magic to make this do what you want it to do. I did this by just adding the below element in your HTML, but with the `hide` class to keep it hidden until it is  needed.

HTML:

```
<label id="tester" class="btn btn-primary active">
    <span id="test" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok hide"></span>
    <input type="radio" name="options" class="option1" checked>Option 1 (preselected)
</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#tester').on('click', function () {
    $('#test').removeClass('hide');
    $('#test2').addClass('hide');
    $('#test3').addClass('hide');
});
```

Where, on click the label, the span will remove the `hide` class, thus showing the check mark while adding the class to the other two inputs. This should work for you, and I would advise changing the name scheme around as well. An example is found below.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e9x38/4/)**

**EDIT**

I updated the fiddle so that the pre-selected option will automatically start with a check mark, hopefully creating the experience you are looking for.